# How to find when a Group is created on the system?

Tags: group

I am wondering how to find any information about the timestamp of group creation on our system?
[This article](https://it.toolbox.com/question/how-to-find-out-when-a-user-is-created-in-linux-030612) really helped me to trace back the user creation, but not for group. 
Any helps really appreciated.

Comment: If you have used `sudo` for the group creation, there should be a log entry for it. Otherwise - as the linked page states - you'll need to have something like `auditd` configured to monitor for such changes.

Comment: you can forward your bash_history or logs to any log analyzer such as Splunk & then you can have timestamp which user did what & at what time.